# icon_url is not a valid syntax for discord bot

Tags: python, discord, embed

I was trying to set the icon footer for an embedded message for bot I'm making by using icon_url = "" but it seems that it's not a valid syntax

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title = f"{bot.user.name} Online!",
    color = discord.Color.teal()

)
embed.set_footer(
text = "footer"
icon_url = "https://i.ibb.co/Z8dRtL3/Letter-B-line-geometric-logo-vector.jpg"

)
log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
await log_channel.send(embed = embed)
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> File "main.py", line 23
> icon_url = "https://i.ibb.co/Z8dRtL3/Letter-B-line-geometric-logo-vector.jpg"
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You missed a comma.

Comment: OMG TYSM ILY <3